# Is it possible to have Wordpress use an ASP.NET authentication mechanism?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wordpress

I have an asp.net website with users login implemented. Now I want to add a blog to it with Wordpress.

The company that hosts the server I use said it is possible to create a folder for wordpress in the same server/internet domain as Windows supports php.

Now my question is: Is it possible to have Wordpress use my ASP.NET user authentication mechanism?

For instance, when a user wants to comment on a post (on Wordpress engine), I’d like that the post goes with the user name and picture that is on my asp.net user data implementation.

Otherwise the user would need to have two different logins on the same site (one for the ASP.NET part and another for the Wordpress part) which is bad from an usability / user experience perspective.

Maybe there’s a Wordpress plugin for this integration that I don’t know of. Or if it can be done by code, I’d appreciate your help also.

Thank you.

Comment: Not in the way you're thinking of(at least that I know of). Closest thing I can think of is if a user comes to your `php` site get their cookie associated with ASP.NET's session(or however you're keeping track of the user) and use `php`'s `curl` function to post back to the ASP.NET site with that cookie, get the user contents and send back to `php`. After you have the user's data check if there is a wordpress account associated with it in the database. If yes log them in manually, if not make one and log them in manually. But this would be a good amount of programming & wouldn't be perfect.

Comment: thank you for the idea Adam. But like you said it would be a good amount of programming & woulnd't be perfect. Was looking for something more simple.

Comment: just found now there's na IIS plugin to integrate ASP.NET authentication with Wordpress: http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/08/iis-authentication-plugin-for-wordpress

Has anyone tried it?

Comment: also found there's phalanger that might do the work. Did not try though.
http://www.infoq.com/articles/Phalanger